# Get class type during dependency resoluton

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, constructor-injection

When registering a type for my unity container, I need to pass in the calling class's type into the constructor of the resolved object.

This is the class where I am injecting some interfaces into the constructor.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    internal class ProcessingService: IProcessingService
    {
        private readonly ISomeClass1 someClass1;
        private readonly ISomeClass2 someClass2;

        public ProcessingService(ISomeClass1 someClass1, ISomeClass2 someClass2)
        {
            this.someClass1 = someClass1;
            this.someClass2 = someClass2;
        }
    }
}
```

SomeClass2 expects Type in the constructor:

```
public class SomeClass2
{
    public SomeClass2(Type type)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Here is my unity bootstrap class where I set up my container.  Now, for ISomeClass2, when it resolves to SomeClass2, it needs to pass in the type of ProcessingService.

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class UnityBootstrap : IUnityBootstrap
    {
        public IUnityContainer Configure(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            return container
                .RegisterType<ISomeClass1, SomeClass1>()
                .RegisterType<ISomeClass2>(new InjectionFactory(fac =>
                {
                    // IMethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType is returning MyNamespace.UnityBootstrap
                    // whereas I need to get MyNamespace.ProcessingService
                    return new SomeClass2(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this using the InjectionFactory (or some other way within my Configure method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have control over the `ProcessingService`, you could create a generic wrapper around `SomeClass2` and then register it using open generics.  But that would require you modify the constructor of the `ProcessingService`.

```
public interface IGenericSomeClass2<T>: ISomeClass2 {}

public class GenericSomeClass2<T>: IGenericSomeClass2<T>
{
    private readonly ISomeClass2 someClass2;
    public GenericSomeClass2()
    {
        this.someClass2 = new SomeClass2(typeof(T));
    }
    // Pass-through implementation
}

public IUnityContainer Configure(IUnityContainer container)
{
    return container
        .RegisterType<ISomeClass1, SomeClass1>()
        .RegisterType(typeof(IGenericSomeClass2<>), typeof(GenericSomeClass2<>));
}

internal class ProcessingService: IProcessingService
{
    private readonly ISomeClass1 someClass1;
    private readonly ISomeClass2 someClass2;

    public ProcessingService(ISomeClass1 someClass1, IGenericSomeClass2<ProcessingService> someClass2)
    {
        this.someClass1 = someClass1;
        this.someClass2 = someClass2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, there are two points of view to this problem:

1) If `SomeClass2` will always use the type `ProcessingService` then you can pass the type argument directly into the `InjectionFactory`

```
container.RegisterType<ISomeClass2>(new InjectionFactory(_ =>
{
    return new SomeClass2(typeof(ProcessingService));
}));
```

2) Otherwise, if the type argument differs throughout application you should consider adding a registration method to interface `ISomeClass2` and register the type from within the constructor to emphasize the dependency/variation.

```
public interface ISomeClass2
{
    void DoSomething();
    void RegisterProcessingServiceType(Type processingServiceType);
}

public class SomeClass2 : ISomeClass2
{
    private Type _type;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        if(_type == null)
            throw InvalidOperationException("Register processing service type before doing stuff.");
        // actually do something
    }

    public void RegisterProcessingServiceType(Type serviceType)
    {
        _type = serviceType;
    }
}

internal class ProcessingService: IProcessingService
{
    private readonly ISomeClass1 someClass1;
    private readonly ISomeClass2 someClass2;

    public ProcessingService(ISomeClass1 someClass1, ISomeClass2 someClass2)
    {
        this.someClass1 = someClass1;
        this.someClass2 = someClass2;
        this.someClass2.RegisterProcessingServiceType(this.GetType());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Yes, SomeClass2 can be used (and is used) by several classes within my project.  SomeClass2 is in a library that was provided to me of which I do not have the source and cannot change; so I need to pass it in to its constructor as designed.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not control `ProcessingService` (or other consumers of SomeClass2), you could customize the registration of those consumers.  This method is a bit more intrusive because you would have to create an injection factory for every consumer.

```
container
    .RegisterType<IProcessingService, ProcessingService>(new InjectionFactory((c, type, name) =>
    {
        return new ProcessingService(c.Resolve<ISomeClass1>(), new SomeClass2(type));
    }));
```